# UIScrollView not key value coding compliant for key view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, key-value-coding

So following this SO question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960951/how-to-create-many-elements-in-interface-builder-that-overflow-beyond-the-xib), i created two new sets of files:

```
JCScrollViewController.m  
JCScrollViewController.xib

JCKeyboard.xib
```

In `JCScrollViewController.xib` i have just a scroll view, with the `scrollView` outlet of the .m file connected to it, the view outlet is connected to the View. The `JCScrollViewController.m` conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

In my app delegate i do this:

```
JCScrollViewController *viewController = [[JCScrollViewController alloc] init];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

---

In `JCScrollViewController.m` i do this in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
//load your JCKeyboard.xib into a UIView object
NSArray *nibParts = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"JCKeyboard" 
                                                  owner:nil 
                                                options:nil];
//first object is the view
UIView *keyboard = [nibParts objectAtIndex:0];

//add keyboard to scrollView 
[scrollView addSubview:keyboard];

//set content size to same dimensions as TallView.xib
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
```

---

When i launch the app i get this error:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.
```

What would cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your JCScrollViewController properly extend UIViewController? If unsure, show your header file.

You probably have a link to something called "view" in IB, whereas the class linked to doesn't have an IBOutlet called "view" - hence the error. IB should show this as a yellow-ish link.